# Doctrine Query with *

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I do have table called zipcodes. The length of a zipcode is five. How can I create a query in Doctrine that I get the result, when I only submit 3 characters to the query.

Example:

```
$search_zipcode = 123*

Table: 
Id  Zipcode
1 - 12345
2 - 12346
3 - 98123
4 - 91238
```

The result ist just id 1 and 2. I don't want to have id 3 and 4.

Thanks!

Gunnar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `LIKE` operator and `%` wildcard

```
->where('z.ZipCode LIKE ?', array($search_zipcode . '%')
```